# R data.table one line statement dealing with confusing variable name

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose `dt` is a `data.table` object with columns `A`, `B` and `C`.

I want loop over the columns to filter out some rows, AND then apply a function on that column:

```
for(col in c("A", "B", "C")){
  dt[col %in% some_filter[[col], col := some_function(col), with=FALSE]
}
```

Where `some_filter` is a `list` containing some valid values, for example `some_filter[["A"]] = c("just", "an", "example")` , etc.

However by referring to `col` in those 4 positions, `data.table` seems to mess up the namespace and fail miserably.

There is a work around via temporary variables, but how to do this task in one line?

A not working code is:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
dt <- data.table(A=1:10, B=11:20, C=21:30)
f <- list()
f[["A"]] <- 3:5
f[["B"]] <- 14:18
f[["C"]] <- 28:29
for(col in colnames(dt)){
  dt[col %in% f[[col]], col := col * 2, with=F] # Double up some rows
}
```

Comment: Could you add the expected output to the question. Maybe what you want is `get(col)` in the data.table call

Comment: Yes, please fill `f` with live (i.e. example function(s)) and add the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `get` to access columns from a character variable containing their names.  `()` around the LHS of `:=` is also preferred to using `with = F`

```
for(col in colnames(dt)){
  dt[get(col) %in% f[[col]], (col) := get(col) * 2L] # Double up some rows
}

#     A  B  C
# 1:  1 11 21
# 2:  2 12 22
# 3:  6 13 23
# 4:  8 28 24
# 5: 10 30 25
# 6:  6 32 26
# 7:  7 34 27
# 8:  8 36 56
# 9:  9 19 58
# 10: 10 20 30
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use `set`

```
for(nm1 in names(dt)) {
   i1 <- which(dt[[nm1]] %in% f[[nm1]])
   set(dt, i= i1, j = nm1, value = dt[[nm1]][i1]*2L)
 }
dt
#     A  B  C
# 1:  1 11 21
# 2:  2 12 22
# 3:  6 13 23
# 4:  8 28 24
# 5: 10 30 25
# 6:  6 32 26
# 7:  7 34 27
# 8:  8 36 56
# 9:  9 19 58
#10: 10 20 30
```